# Subtract two values with different path in realtime database and save the result in different path

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to substract two values from different path of the database and save the result in the database. This should be done for every group (e.g. 1551406426951) all users within each group (e.g. n8pn...r1).

Then save the count as shown in the database tree. A code sample would be very helpful.

---

totalMessages - readMessages = count
30 - 17 = 13

save count in each userId-path (s. structure)

Structure is as follows:

```
groupId1
  totalMessages
  userId1
    readMessages
    count<-save here
  userId2
    readMessages
    count<-save here
  ...
groupId2
  totalMessages
  userId1
    readMessages
    count<-save here
  userId2
    readMessages
    count<-save here
  ...
```

[image]

---

Code enclosed.
It writes 'count' under the correct userId but it is the same value as 'readMessages'. I am trying to receive the const 'test' to substract readMessages from it. But not sure how to build the substraction.

```
     exports.readMessages = functions.database.ref('messageCounter/{groupid}/{userid}/readMessages/')
.onWrite((change, context) => {

const group = context.params.groupid;
const user = context.params.userid;
const readMessages = change.after.val();
  console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.groupid, readMessages);

const test = functions.database.ref('messageCounter/{groupid}/totalMessages')

  return admin.database().ref('messageCounter/'+group+'/'+user).child('count').set(readMessages);
});
```

Comment: *"A code sample would be very helpful."* Typically, one posts to Stack Overflow with code they've written that doesn't work the way they expect. It is not a free code writing service.  Please make an attempt at solving your problem, and post again if you're stuck with what you've written, explaining how it doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I understand, I edited my answer and included my code.